# Binding data frames created by loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a number of R scripts that create data frames of the same length and I am trying to aggregate all the data frames into one.

I used a for loop to run those R scripts:

```
for(i in sample){
  source(i)
}
```

This does create all the data frames I need.  But is there a good way to include a function that binds those data frames together within that for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `source(i)` returns a data frame, you can combine all the data frames together with something like:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(sample, source))
```